# Finding similar or overlapping groups of times in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of start and end times, `my_list`, which contains different groupings of start and end times.

- 8:45 - 11:00
- 9:00 - 11:00
- 9:15 - 11:00
- 9:30 - 11:00
- 12:30 - 15:00
- 12:30 - 15:00
- 12:45 - 15:00

These records are group therapy session start/end times for patients entered by one therapist.  I need similar times grouped together so that I can check if there were more than 3 lists in the groupings.  So from 9:00 - 11:00, there were 4 patients when the rules only allow 3.

This [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885188/checking-for-overlap-between-time-spans) answers provide help for help finding all of the overlapping times in one given list and I've tried variations of the solutions posted there.  But I need to find overlapping times based on groups of similar times.

```py
my_list = [
  [dt.time(8,45), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,0), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,15), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,30), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(12,30), dt.time(15,0)],
  [dt.time(12,30), dt.time(15,0)],
  [dt.time(12,45), dt.time(15,0)],
  ]
```

I need to group similar/duplicated/overlapping times...

```py
group_one = [
  [dt.time(8,45), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,0), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,15), dt.time(11,0)],
  [dt.time(9,30), dt.time(11,0)]
]

group_two = [
  [dt.time(12,30), dt.time(15,0)],
  [dt.time(12,30), dt.time(15,0)],
  [dt.time(12,45), dt.time(15,15)]
]
```

Eventually, checking `len(group_one) > 3` returns `True`

```py
# Pseudo-code
 for times in my_list:
  if start or end times are equal to or overlap each other:
    throw the times into separate, similar lists (or dicts where key = timeslot?)
  else:
    if start or end times....
```

Solution can be pure Python or Pandas as this data is coming from a dataframe and will be manipulated there.  I can't help but feel there is a magical way of doing this in Pandas, just stuck!

Edit: changed data in question to match answer.

Comment: Is the end time always the same as your example?

Comment: How is the pandas Series structured? So how was `my_list` created?

Comment: What do you do with a cascade of overlaps?  For instance, with intervals of 9-12, 10-2, and 1-3, what will your groups be?  The first and last don't overlap, but each overlaps the middle.

Comment: @Erfan no, each start/end time could be different.  For example, four different sets of times might only share the times of 9:45-10:00

Comment: @Josmoor98 each row in df contains a StartTime and EndTime column.  I throw them all into one list based on a groupby of another column value.  @ Prune that wouldn't happen.  The group schedule times are set.  Variations in times just means the patient came in early/late, or left early/late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe looks something like this and there are no cascading overlaps as pointed out in the comments by [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2019, 8, 7, 8, 45),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 11)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 9),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 11)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 9, 15),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 11)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 9, 30), datetime(2019, 8, 7, 11)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 12, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 12, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 12, 45),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 17)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 17)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 15, 45),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 17)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 18, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 19)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 18, 30),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 19)],
                   [datetime(2019, 8, 7, 18, 45),datetime(2019, 8, 7, 19)]], 
                   columns = ["start", "end"])
```

If the data structure in your question is consistent with all of your data, then the following should work. If there any cascading cases, as pointed out, this won't work.

---

**Note, `df['start']` needs to be sorted for this procedure to work**.

---

```
idx = df.index[(df['end'].shift() <= df['start'])]
overlapping groups = np.split(df, idx)
```

Which yields a list of `DataFrames`.

```
[                start                 end
 0 2019-08-07 08:45:00 2019-08-07 11:00:00
 1 2019-08-07 09:00:00 2019-08-07 11:00:00
 2 2019-08-07 09:15:00 2019-08-07 11:00:00
 3 2019-08-07 09:30:00 2019-08-07 11:00:00,
                 start                 end
 4 2019-08-07 12:30:00 2019-08-07 15:00:00
 5 2019-08-07 12:30:00 2019-08-07 15:00:00
 6 2019-08-07 12:45:00 2019-08-07 15:00:00,
                 start                 end
 7 2019-08-07 15:30:00 2019-08-07 17:00:00
 8 2019-08-07 15:30:00 2019-08-07 17:00:00
 9 2019-08-07 15:45:00 2019-08-07 17:00:00,
                 start                 end
10 2019-08-07 18:30:00 2019-08-07 19:00:00
11 2019-08-07 18:30:00 2019-08-07 19:00:00
12 2019-08-07 18:45:00 2019-08-07 19:00:00]
```

Comment: Changing the very first start time to ```datetime(2019, 8, 7, 8, 45)``` results in one less overlapping group.

Comment: Updated, it also didn't catch the last group. `np.split` resolves the issues raised. Let me know if there any more issues

Comment: modifying an end time that butts right up to another time throws it off.  For example, ```datetime(2019,8,7,9,30), datetime(2019,8,7,12,30)``` adds this record to the second grouping when it should be in the first.

Comment: To solve that specific issue, you can use `idx = df.index[(df['end'].shift() <= df['start'])]` instead. So just replace `<` with `<=`. That seems to work on my example code, but may not catch all cases. If that works, I will update the solution