# Is there a faster way to check if a number is within an interval?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of intervals that I have been sorting like this:

```
intervals=['132-237','156-223','589-605',...]
```

I then get a number and want to determine which intervals it is included in:

```
number=160 #number gotten
for lines in intervals:
    lines=line.split(sep='-')
    if number>=int(lines[0]) and number<=int(lines[1]):
        record=record+1 #actually recording it more complicated
```

is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: Use a tree structure (or a heap).

Comment: Apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446112/search-for-interval-overlap-in-list-of-intervals with a one point interval `[a,b] = [number, number]

Comment: Look into implementing an interval tree.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a for loop? If speed is the concern because you have a gigantic list of intervals, I don't think python is your answer.

Comment: @Decency Using a loop is an O(n) algorithm. An appropriate data structure would allow O(lg n) lookups - a substantial improvement regardless of the language involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list of tuples.

```
intervals = [(132,237),(156,223),(589,605)]
number = 160
for start, stop in intervals:
    if start <= number <= stop:
        print (start, stop)
```

As you asked explicitly for a solution without a `for`-loop, please look at Markku K's comment to this answer.

If you want to avoid `for` at all, I fear the way to go is recursion for which python is not cut out.

Comment: Since the OP asked for a solution without a 'for loop', you could use a list comprehension instead: `[tup for tup in intervals if tup[0] <= number <= tup[1]]`.

Comment: @MarkkuK. Thank you I overlooked that part. Although I don't know which is the advantage of a `for` in a list comprehension, compared to an explicit `for`-loop. I will update my answer.

Comment: Right, it really isn't a big difference. I initially posted that suggestion as a separate answer, but decided the change was so insignificant, that I would just write a comment instead.

Comment: +1 for not parsing strings. And yes, a list comprehension is a solution - a loop not visible to coder - but it is not faster in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
intervals = ['132-237','156-223','589-605']
intervals = [tuple(map(int, i.split('-'))) for i in intervals]
number = 160
for low,high in intervals:
    if low <= number <= high:
        print(number, "is between", low, "and", high)
        break
```

Of course, a binary search would be faster:

```
intervals = ['132-237','156-223','589-605']
intervals = [tuple(map(int, i.split('-'))) for i in intervals]
def binSearch(number, intervals):
    intervals.sort()
    mid = len(intervals)//2  # a//b is in python3. Use len(intervals)/2 for python2
    low,high = intervals[mid]
    if number > high:
        return binSearch(number, intervals[mid+1:])
    elif number < low:
        return binSearch(number, intervals[:mid])
    elif low <= number <= high:
        return (low,high)
    else:
        return "no appropriate interval exists"
```

Comment: OP: "want to determine which intervals it is included in".

Comment: `//` works the same in Python 2.2 and later as it does in Python 3. It's `/` that works differently in Python 3 than it did in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
def inside_interval(num, interval):
    start, end = interval.split(sep='-')
    return num in range(int(start), int(end))
```

And some sample output:

```
intervals = ['132-237', '156-223', '589-605']
print(inside_interval(150, intervals[0]))
print(inside_interval(123, intervals[1]))
print(inside_interval(600, intervals[2]))
# True, False, True
```

Here's using the example with a for loop (in a list comprehension). You could use another construct here if you really wanted to, but you'd need a good reason to do so.

```
num = 160
intervals_list = [inside_interval(num, interval) for interval in intervals]
# intervals_list = [True, True, False]
```

This gets you an output of Booleans that correspond to your list of intervals.

I'd personally suggest that you turn your intervals into a more useful format, rather than using strings. That will make it easier to do other comparisons.