# Histogram-like summary for interval data

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

How do I get a histogram-like summary of interval data in R?

My MWE data has four intervals.

```
interval  range
Int1      2-7
Int2      10-14
Int3      12-18
Int4      25-28
```

I want a histogram-like function which counts how the intervals Int1-Int4 span a range split across fixed-size bins.
The function output should look like this:

```
bin     count  which
[0-4]   1      Int1
[5-9]   1      Int1
[10-14] 2      Int2 and Int3
[15-19] 1      Int3
[20-24] 0      None
[25-29] 1      Int4
```

Here the range is [minfloor(Int1, Int2, Int3, Int40), maxceil(Int1, Int2, Int3, Int4)) = [0,30) and there are six bins of size = 5.

I would greatly appreciate any pointers to R packages or functions that implement the functionality I want.

**Update:**

So far, I have a solution from the IRanges package which uses a fast data structure called NCList, which is faster than Interval Search Trees according to users.

```
> library(IRanges)
> subject <- IRanges(c(2,10,12,25), c(7,14,18,28))
> query <- IRanges(c(0,5,10,15,20,25), c(4,9,14,19,24,29))
> countOverlaps(query, subject)
[1] 1 1 2 1 0 1
```

But I am still unable to get which are the ranges that overlap. Will update if I get through.

Comment: Have you tried with `table`?

Comment: I tried table but could not go beyond a naive implementation of querying for every range end point i.e., check [i,j] overlaps [k,l] if j>k and i<l. (Idea taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446112/search-for-interval-overlap-in-list-of-intervals)

Comment: Is your expected output based on the input example?  I would try `cut` with `breaks`

Comment: How do I get 'cut' to work on intervals? I am under the impression that 'cut' works on vectors. (Sorry about poor formatting.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978837/histogram-like-summary-for-interval-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IRanges`, you should use `findOverlaps` or `mergeByOverlaps` instead of `countOverlaps`. It, by default, doesn't return *no matches* though.

I'll leave that to you. Instead, will show an alternate method using `foverlaps()` from `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table)
subject <- data.table(interval = paste("int", 1:4, sep=""), 
                      start = c(2,10,12,25), 
                      end = c(7,14,18,28))
query <- data.table(start = c(0,5,10,15,20,25), 
                    end = c(4,9,14,19,24,29))

setkey(subject, start, end)
ans = foverlaps(query, subject, type="any")
ans[, .(count = sum(!is.na(start)), 
        which = paste(interval, collapse=", ")), 
     by = .(i.start, i.end)]

#    i.start i.end count      which
# 1:       0     4     1       int1
# 2:       5     9     1       int1
# 3:      10    14     2 int2, int3
# 4:      15    19     1       int3
# 5:      20    24     0         NA
# 6:      25    29     1       int4
```

Comment: Any comments on speed of foverlaps Vs. IRanges ? Does foverlaps use a special datastructure/algorithm like NCList ?